# Validate HTML missing div,table tags?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-2.0

Is there a way to validate my ASPX page code? I have plenty of missing div tags, missing td tags etc on my page. How can I catch all my html errors ? The Visual Studio aspx editor won't help that much. Is there any tool to facilitate this ? How would you guys go about these tasks ?

Comment: Why won't the built in studio editor help? It has a built in validator that should be pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to copy the url of the page to [this validator](http://validator.w3.org/) if you got a online version otherwise open the page in browsers and copy the source of into [here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

View your page using Opera browser, then right-click->validate. It sends the page source to the W3C validator.

Answer (score 1):

Try the W3 validator. http://validator.w3.org/